# *NgFor toggle show/hide individual element

Tags: javascript, angular, toggle, ngfor

I have that piece of code in HTML:

```
<!-- Toggle show hide -->
    <ng-container *ngFor="let plate of plates; let i=index">
      <button (click)="toggle(plate)">{{i}}. {{ buttonName }}</button>
      <span *ngIf="!show">
        <i>{{i}}</i>
        <h1>{{ plate.PlateNumber }}</h1>
      </span>
    </ng-container>
```

And Angular code:

```
toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    // CHANGE THE NAME OF THE BUTTON.
    if (this.show)
      this.buttonName = "Show";
    else
      this.buttonName = "Hide";
  }
```

It works ok, but I need that when I clicked on button it hides that particular `<span>` container. I added images to illustrate what I want to do, but when i press button it hides all elements.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `this` represents the whole component, not a particuler plate. This is why it hides/shows everything, it's a component-level variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a property called `show` in the `plate` object and then change the value depend on the `click`.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let plate of plates; let i=index">
      <button (click)="toggle(plate)">{{i}}. {{ buttonName }}</button>
      <span *ngIf="!plate.show">
        <i>{{i}}</i>
        <h1>{{ plate.PlateNumber }}</h1>
      </span>
 </ng-container>

 toggle(plate) {
    plate.show = !plate.show;

    // CHANGE THE NAME OF THE BUTTON.
    if (plate.show)
      this.buttonName = "Show";
    else
      this.buttonName = "Hide";
  }
```

Comment: I knew it was simple. Thank you so much! You're life saver :)

Comment: Cool. make sure to check as answer if this helped.